# Charge density of a point charge given the 4-current

Tags: electromagnetism

I am stuck with what seems a pretty straightforward problem concerning the charge density $\rho$ of a moving point charge.

Given the trajectory $\mathbf{r}(t)$ of the moving charge $q$ in an arbitrary frame of reference, I know that its charge density is:
\begin{equation}
\rho(\mathbf{x},t)=q\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(t))
\tag{1}
\end{equation}
I also know that one can write a general expression for the current density 4-vector:
\begin{equation}
j^\mu=cq\int\delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau))\,u^\mu(\tau)\,d\tau
\tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $\tau$ is proper time and $u^\mu(\tau)$ is the charge 4-velocity.

Since $j^0=c\rho$, I would like to derive (1) given (2).

Answer (score 3):

Starting from (2), you get
\begin{equation*}
j^\mu=cq\int\delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau))\,u^\mu(\tau)\,d\tau
\tag{1}
\end{equation*}
from which $u^{\mu}=\frac{dx^{\mu}}{d\tau}$. Then, setting $\mu=0$, yields
\begin{equation*}
j^0=cq\int\delta^{(4)}(x-r(\tau))\,dx^0
\tag{2}
\end{equation*}
and by considering that $\delta^4(x-r(\tau))=\delta(ct-r^0(\tau))\delta^3(\vec{x}-\vec{r}(\tau))$, yields the desired result.

Comment: Shouldn't the 4-velocity be written as $u^\mu=\frac{dr^\mu}{d\tau}$? In that case one gets:
\begin{equation}
j^0=cq\int\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(\tau))\,\delta(ct-r^0(\tau))\,dr^0
\end{equation}
Now, if $r^0=c\tau$ (which still leaves me a bit puzzled), then one can show (using the scaling property of the Dirac delta) that:
\begin{equation}
j^0=cq\int\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(\tau))\,\delta(t-\tau)\,d\tau=cq\,\delta^{(3)}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{r}(t))=c\rho(\mathbf{x},t)
\end{equation}
Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Why is $r^0$ proportional to the proper time?

Comment: Because I want to parameterize the particle's trajectory as a function of proper time, hence I feel inclined to put $r^\mu=(c\tau,\mathbf{r}(\tau))$, even though I am not 100% sure.

Comment: $r^{\mu}$ is defined as $(ct,\vec{r})$. Either $t$ or $\vec{r}$ can be functions of $\tau$